# Three.js import obj and mtl with OBJMTLLoader

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have a dog.max model, I export it to dog.obj and dog.mtl by 3dmax, and I use them in my three.js project like this:

```
var loader = new THREE.OBJMTLLoader();
loader.load( '2/dog.obj', '2/dog.mtl', function ( obj ) {
    alert( "1" );
    mesh = obj; 
    obj.position.set( 0, 0, -10 );
    scene.add( obj ); 
    mesh.position.set( 0, 0, -600 );
} );
```

but when I open it in my service (tomcat7.0), firefox said the script has no response. Is the model too complex for the browser to work with them?

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit? Jsfiddle?

Comment: Well,thanks for reply,I got something  last night,when I choice ignore when the browser has no response,and wait for a minutes,everthing is solved,the 3d Object works ok. so I think the problem is that the browser take a long time to render the modle,and it seems like died,but how to deal with it?

Comment: ps:sorry for my English capability,but I think you can understand it.:)

Comment: dog.obj:4M dog.mtl:3KB,and tow images:317KB and 37KB. 4M is too big?If so,how to optimize it when I export with 3dMax?